# DynamicMethod with generic type parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

Is it possible to define a DynamicMethod with generic type parameters? The MethodBuilder class has the DefineGenericParameters method. Does the DynamicMethod have a counterpart? For example is it possible to create method with a signature like the one given blow using DynamicMethod?

```
void T Foo<T>(T a1, int a2)
```

Comment: If you are dynamically creating the method then wouldn't you know the types when you generate the method? Which would remove the need to have a generic dynamic method?

Comment: I'm writing a little interpreter and I want to use DynamicMethods to compile the functions. The language has support for parametric polymorphism and it would have been nice to use type parameters and not have to generate overloads for each parameter combination.

Comment: See: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2508820-dynamicmethod-to-support-generic-type-parameters-l to vote on having support added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a way, it's not exactly generic but you'll get the idea:

```
public delegate T Foo<T>(T a1, int a2);

public class Dynamic<T>
{
    public static readonly Foo<T> Foo = GenerateFoo<T>();

    private static Foo<V> GenerateFoo<V>()
    {
        Type[] args = { typeof(V), typeof(int)};

        DynamicMethod method =
            new DynamicMethod("FooDynamic", typeof(V), args);

        // emit it

        return (Foo<V>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Foo<V>));
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Dynamic<double>.Foo(1.0, 3);
```

Comment: Actually, that's no a bad idea :). I'll keep it in mind if I ever face this issue again. I'm also selecting your reply as an answer since it gets close to solving the original problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't appear to be possible: as you've seen `DynamicMethod` has no `DefineGenericParameters` method, and it inherits `MakeGenericMethod` from its `MethodInfo` base class, which just throws `NotSupportedException`.

A couple of possibilities:

- Define a whole dynamic assembly using `AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly`
- Do generics yourself, by generating the same `DynamicMethod` once for each set of type arguments

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. I guess there's no other way. Though it would be nice to have support for this with DynamicMethods.