# Using DynamicMethod to invoke a method with generic parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

My goal here is to create a method `SortRecords` that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` and a `PropertyInfo` as parameters.  The `IEnumerable<T>` is a list of records.  The `PropertyInfo` is a property of of `T`.  When invoked, `SortRecords` should invoke the `Enumerable.SortBy<T, typeof Property>` method with `x => x.Property`.  Note here that `Enumerable.SortBy` has two generic parameters.  Also, reflection cannot be used inside the lambda expression because (a) it is slow and (b) it won't work with Entity Framework.

I have written some code, but I keep seeing the error message `Operation could destabilize the runtime`.  Here is what my code looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSorts; i++)
        {
            string propertyName = PropertyNames[ColumnSortOrder[i]];
            PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == propertyName);              

            Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>> sortingFunction = GetFunctionToSortRecords<T>(filteredRecords, property);
            sortedRecords = GetFunctionToSortRecords<T>(filteredRecords, property)(filteredRecords, property);
         }
```

end first code snippet

Method definitions follow

```
delegate IEnumerable<T> GetFunctionToSortRecordsDelegate<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, PropertyInfo propertyToSortOn);
public static Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>> GetFunctionToSortRecords<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, PropertyInfo propertyToSortOn)
    {
        Type propertyType = propertyToSortOn.GetType();

        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("SortRecords", typeof(IEnumerable<T>), new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>), typeof(PropertyInfo) });            
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();            

        MethodInfo GetPropertyValue = propertyToSortOn.GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo GetDefaultKeySelectorForProperty = typeof(DataTablesSorting).GetMethod("GetDefaultKeySelectorForProperty")                                                                                                         
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {typeof(T), propertyToSortOn.PropertyType });            

        MethodInfo EnumerableOrderBy = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
            .Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Count()==3);

        // Get the default key selector for the property passed in.            
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // property
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetDefaultKeySelectorForProperty);

        // Save the default key selector at location 0
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // records
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); // default key selector
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, EnumerableOrderBy);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return ((GetFunctionToSortRecordsDelegate<T>)(method.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetFunctionToSortRecordsDelegate<T>)))).Invoke;
    }

    delegate TKey GetDefaultKeySelectorForPropertyDelegate<T, TKey>(T t);
    public static Func<T, TKey> GetDefaultKeySelectorForProperty<T, TKey>(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("GetKeySelector", typeof(TKey), new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

        MethodInfo GetPropertyValue = property.GetGetMethod();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, GetPropertyValue);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return ((GetDefaultKeySelectorForPropertyDelegate<T, TKey>)(method.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetDefaultKeySelectorForPropertyDelegate<T, TKey>)))).Invoke;
    }
```

I think that this question may be related: [DynamicMethod with generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788618/dynamicmethod-with-generic-type-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `DynamicMethod` myself like this, but I suspect you just need to `MakeGenericMethod` on this `EnumerableOrderBy` just like you're already doing for `GetDefaultKeySelectorForProperty`. At the moment you're trying to call the generic method without specifying any type arguments.

So something like:

```
MethodInfo EnumerableOrderBy = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "OrderBy" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 3)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propertyToSortOn.PropertyType);
```

([`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) uses a parameter array, so you don't need to explicitly construct the `Type[]` to pass in.)

(If you need to work with Entity Framework, I've have thought you'd be looking at `Queryable` rather than `Enumerable` and building expression trees instead of delegates, but that's another matter.)

Comment: You've made an important observation, no doubt, but even when I apply the change you suggest, I'm still getting the `Operation could destabilize the runtime` error.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: At which point? A short but complete example would help here - if you can reproduce it with a shorter block of IL (e.g. pass in the ordering delegate) that would help too.

Comment: I tried rewriting the code using reflection and found that I needed the two-parameter `OrderBy` method.  I think that this is definitely one problem, but I'm still getting that same error message when trying to use Dynamic Method.  I think that perhaps the solution might be to cleanly wrap the generic OrderBy method in a method that uses Dynamic method and invoke that...

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: You *should* be able to get it to work. I would reduce the problem to a dynamic method which *just* acts as a proxy to `OrderBy`, and go from there. (Sorry for not spotting that you needed the two-parameter `OrderBy` call... I should have seen that.)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Expressions for this kind of problem.  Here is an example that should work for you.

```
    public static Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>> GetFunctionToSortRecords<T>(IEnumerable<T> records, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var propertyExpression = GetExpressionForProperty<T>(property);
        var method = typeof(TheCurrentClass).GetMethod("InternalGetFunctionToSortRecords", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        return (Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>>)method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), property.PropertyType).Invoke(null, new object[] { propertyExpression });
    }

    private static Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>> InternalGetFunctionToSortRecords<T, TProp>(Expression propertyExpression)
    {
        var lambdaExpression = propertyExpression as LambdaExpression;
        Func<T, TProp> keySelector = (Func<T, TProp>)lambdaExpression.Compile();
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, PropertyInfo, IEnumerable<T>> sorter = (x, y) => x.OrderBy(keySelector);

        return sorter.Invoke;
    }

    private static Expression GetExpressionForProperty<T>(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, parameter);

        return lambdaExpression;
    }
```